# SQL Server : getting data from multiple rows into one row

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table and I want to get one row per user (`userId`) with the `Answer` column value when initial is set to both true and false. So the following tables

```
UserId                              QuestionId   Answer  Initial
----------------------------------------------------------------
027D76AC-DFBC-4BD2-9B88DD7B2456338E 1            5       False
027D76AC-DFBC-4BD2-9B88DD7B2456338E 1            4       True
06B1713D-2E47-4454-8949C950C58753DC 1            4       True
216F33EF-1ACD-4D1F-86D2932AF598326E 1            5       False
216F33EF-1ACD-4D1F-86D2932AF598326E 1            4       True
23A950EB-3C68-4FE7-B719B86DC299343D 1            4       True
23A950EB-3C68-4FE7-B719B86DC299343D 1            4       False
```

Would return the following results

```
UserId                              QuestionId   trueAnswer FalseAnswer
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
027D76AC-DFBC-4BD2-9B88DD7B2456338E 1            5          4
216F33EF-1ACD-4D1F-86D2932AF598326E 1            5          4
23A950EB-3C68-4FE7-B719B86DC299343D 1            4          4
```

Is this something that can be done with sub selects?

Comment: Yes, but why do you want to do this?

Comment: What have you tried?????  It's not clear what you want.  Learn how to ask question here . https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below can be a solution (top portion is just creating a temp table to test it). I am always an advocate of avoiding GROUP BY and plus I think OUTER/CROSS APPLY are really cool. Notice though that the result is opposite your result. For example, your top one shows the FalseAnswer to be 4. According to the data it is 5. Unless I am missing something.

```
-- creating sample set
IF object_id('tempdb..#YOUR_TABLE') is not null drop table #YOUR_TABLE
CREATE TABLE #YOUR_TABLE (UserID VARCHAR(200), QuestionID INT, Answer INT, Initial BIT)
INSERT INTO #YOUR_TABLE(UserID, QuestionID, Answer, Initial)
Values
('027D76AC-DFBC-4BD2-9B88DD7B2456338E', 1,            5,       'false'),
('027D76AC-DFBC-4BD2-9B88DD7B2456338E', 1,            4,       'true'),
('06B1713D-2E47-4454-8949C950C58753DC', 1,            4,       'true'),
('216F33EF-1ACD-4D1F-86D2932AF598326E', 1,            5,       'false'),
('216F33EF-1ACD-4D1F-86D2932AF598326E', 1,            4,       'true'),
('23A950EB-3C68-4FE7-B719B86DC299343D', 1,            4,       'true'),
('23A950EB-3C68-4FE7-B719B86DC299343D', 1,            4,       'false')

-- solution
SELECT a.UserID,
       a.QuestionID,
       a.Answer,
       b.FalseAnswer
FROM #YOUR_TABLE AS a
     OUTER APPLY
     (
        SELECT y.Answer AS FalseAnswer
        FROM #YOUR_TABLE AS y
        WHERE y.Initial='false' AND a.UserID=y.UserID
     ) AS b
WHERE a.Initial='true' AND b.FalseAnswer IS NOT null
```

output

```
UserID  QuestionID  Answer  FalseAnswer
027D76AC-DFBC-4BD2-9B88DD7B2456338E 1   4   5
216F33EF-1ACD-4D1F-86D2932AF598326E 1   4   5
23A950EB-3C68-4FE7-B719B86DC299343D 1   4   4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select UserID,
       max(QuestionID),
       max(case when Initial = 'True' then Answer end) [trueAnswer],
       max(case when Initial = 'False' then Answer end) [falseAnswer]
from TABLE_NAME
group by UserID
having count(distinct Initial) = 2
```

Comment: This would return users who answered exactly two questions with both answers either "true"  or "false".

Comment: That's what OP wanted :)

Comment: I don't think so.   OP requested "when initial is set to both true and false."   One of each.